# cin.getline() not adding \0 to the end of the array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, cin

I've got a code line as follows:

```
const int maxtext=1000;
char text[maxtext];

cin.getline(text,maxtext);
```

Then when I try to see the

```
sizeof(text)
```

It shows me maxtext, not the length of the input.

what I'm doing wrong?

PD.: I can't use functions of the < string > library.

Comment: Can you show the declarations of `text` and `maxtext`?

Comment: @sftrabbit Edited it so it's a bit clearer.

Comment: @Zasito `sizeof(text)` is just telling you what the size of the array is in bytes. It just happens to be the same as `maxtext` because each element is only one byte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(text)` does not examine the content of `text` (it returns the size in bytes of the object, see [sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)) so whether or not null terminating characters is present in `text` is irrelevant. Use `strlen(text)` instead. Ensure `text` has been populated before using `text`:

```
if (cin.getline(text, maxtext))
{
}
```

It is possible to avoid hard-coding a fixed size for reading into by using [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
std::string text;
if (std::getline(std::cin, text))
{
}
```